# How to send list of string to server in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my application I want send some data to server and for this I used **Retrofit** library.
I should send data such as below:

```
{
  "hours": ["22:05","19:57"]
}
```

I write below codes for **Api services:**

```
@POST("profile")
    suspend fun postSubmitDrug(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Body body: RequestBody):Response<ProfileData>
```

And write below codes info `fragment` for **send data to server:**

```
private lateinit var requestBody: RequestBody
var hourMinuteList = mutableListOf<String>()
val multiPart = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("_method", "post")

multiPart.addFormDataPart("hours[]", parentActivity.hourMinuteList.toString())

requestBody = multiPart.build()
```

**But send this list such as below:**

```
{
  "hours": [22:05,19:57]
}
```

How can I fix it and send list of string to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use com.google.gson, and when you create your retrofitCLient call .addConverterFactory(create(GsonBuilder()))

create data model, ex:

```
data class RequestBody(
 val hours: ArrayList<String>? = null
)
```

and just call your endpoint

```
@POST("profile")
suspend fun postSubmitDrug(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Body body: RequestBody):Response<ProfileData>
```

and this is all, gson will automatically serialize your data to json

Comment: Thanks my friend, but after use this code show me **422** validation error from server and message is this : `hour_minute.0 : invalid hour_minute.0.`

Comment: seems like your backend wait for another data structure, not like you described, check what kind of data structure need for backend

Comment: I find bug, backend get hour with 2 count, such as 09:05 , but I send 9:5 ! For show hours I used **FOR** condition 0 to 23 and minute 0 to 59 . Show hours and minutes to user with wheel effect and for this I fill data from **FOR** condition! How can I fill data such as 09 insead of 9 ?

Comment: if (minutes<10){ //add 0 before minutes, or using DateFormat

Comment: Thanks my friend, but can you send to me full code for this? because I'm amateur and really need this. thanks

Comment: Show me how you add the time to list, to give you a correct answer?

Comment: I accept your answer. Please see my for condition : https://justpaste.it/68afq . Thanks

Comment: if (i < 10) {
   hourList.add("0" + i.toString())
  } else {
   hourList.add(i.toString())
  }   when you select an item from picker you must check the selected hour

Comment: if hour is < 10 add 0 like this "0"+hour.toString()